# Java container that works as a Pod not working in a Job

Tags: java, kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-jobs, istio-sidecar

I'm trying to use a container that contains a Java tool to do some DB migrations on a MySQL database in a Kubernetes Job.

When I run the container locally in Docker (using a MySQL container in the same network), the tool runs as expected.
And if I create a Pod using the container and set the command arguments to point to the `mysql` service running in the same namespace, it does as well.

But if I convert that Pod spec into a Job, the created container can not connect to the MySQL service anymore for some reason.

The container is based on `amazoncorretto:8-al2-jdk` and just copies the JAR to `/opt/`.

The MySQL DB is available through the `mysql` service in the cluster:

```bash
$ kubectl describe service mysql -n <namespace>
Name:              mysql
Namespace:         <namespace>
Labels:            app=mysql
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=mysql
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                <ip>
IPs:               <ip>
Port:              mysql  3306/TCP
TargetPort:        3306/TCP
Endpoints:         <ip>:3306
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

These are the specifications for the Pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: java-tool-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: javatool
    image: <registry>/<image-name>:<version>
    command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
    args: [ "-x", "-c", "/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/<tool>.jar \"jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/<db>\" -u <user> -p<password>" ]
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: <secret>
```

Running the Container as a Pod:

```bash
$ kubectl apply -f /tmp/as-pod.yaml -n <namespace>
pod/java-tool-pod created

$ kubectl logs pod/java-tool-pod -n <namespace>
+ /usr/bin/java -jar /opt/<tool>.jar jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/<db> -u <user> -p<password>
DB Migration Tool
Database Schema, 3.30.0.3300024390, built Wed Jul 14 12:13:52 UTC 2021
Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
INFO Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse
INFO Database: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/<db> (MySQL 5.7)
INFO Validated 721 migrations (execution time 00:00.253s)
INFO Current version of schema `<db>`: 3.29.0.10859.10
WARN outOfOrder mode is active. Migration of schema `<db>` may not be reproducible.
INFO Schema `<db>` is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

These are the specifications for the Job:

```yaml
$ cat /tmp/as-job.yaml 
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: javatool-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: javatool
        image: <registry>/<image-name>:<version>
        command: [ "/bin/sh" ]
        args: [ "-x", "-c", "/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/<tool>.jar \"jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/<db>\" -u <user -p<password>" ]
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: <secret>
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Running the container as a Job:

```bash
$ kubectl apply -f /tmp/as-job.yaml -n <namespace>
job.batch/javatool-job created

$ kubectl logs job.batch/javatool-job -n <namespace>
+ /usr/bin/java -jar /opt/<tool>.jar jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/<db> -u <user> -p<password>
DB Migration Tool
Database Schema, 3.30.0.3300024390, built Wed Jul 14 12:13:52 UTC 2021
Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:339)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2252)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2285)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at com.nordija.itv.db.FlywayMigrationSchemaData.isNotFlywaySchemaVersion(FlywayMigrationSchemaData.java:58)
[...]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:214)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
    ... 22 more
INFO Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse
Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
[...]
```

I haven't seen any significant differences in the containers being created.
The only thing I can think of is some kind of character encoding issue, but I don't see why that should only occur in a Pod that was created for a Job and not in one that was created directly.

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue!

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that Istio is active on the Namespace, which turned out to be causing the issues.

Comment: Are you sure your username and password are correct?

Comment: Yes, the credentials were correct (they were copy & pasted). It turned out to be a problem related to Istio (which I forgot to mention is active in the namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Istio doesn't play nice with Kubernetes Jobs (I forgot to mention that Istio is active on the Namespace, sorry).

Once I added a short delay (`sleep 5` before starting the Java tool), the connection could be established.

But then I had another issue: After the container terminated successfully, the Job would not be marked as completed.

And the reason was again Istio.
Jobs are considered complete once **all** Pods are terminated and the Istio Sidecar is a service Pod that doesn't terminate.
After finding [this article](https://medium.com/redbox-techblog/handling-istio-sidecars-in-kubernetes-jobs-c392661c4af7), I ended up integrating their [`scuttle`](https://github.com/redboxllc/scuttle) tool into the container and now the Job can be completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is "Communications link failure". So I think you should have a look at your Networkpolicies.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it didn't end up being the Network Policies, but Istio delaying the availability of the correct network routing.